# The preview in Android Studio is stuck on "Loading..." and doesn't ever load

Tags: android-studio

[screenshot of my preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz9XQ.png)

I open Android Studio and everything in my project loads except for the preview screen. How can I make the preview load?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I prematurely closed the Android studio while it was building the project.
And when I tried File > Sync Project with Gradle Files, it worked.

Comment: It worked for me @DrDonkey. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me, What was causing the bug was a file named `firestore.rules` (Working on a flutter App)
I've realized that when temporary removing every file (not document) in the project directory.

So what you can do is remove as much files as needed to make it work again, and then add them one by one until it bug again: this is your problematic file.

(you can btw test it immediatly by creating a new project to see if it's not a bug with your android studio software)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is just removing the `.idea` folder.